# Existance and unicity of Cauchy problem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

i have the following Osgood Lemma: let $f(x,y)$ a function such as $|f(x,y_1)-f(x,y_2)| \leq h(|y_2 - y_1|)$ for all $(x,y_1)$ and $(x,y_2)$ in an opena $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$. We suppose that function $h$ is continuous on each point $u \in ]0,\alpha]$, stricly positive and $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \displaystyle\int_{\epsilon}^{\alpha} \dfrac{d u}{h(u)}=+\infty$, with $\alpha > 0$.
Then for all $(x_0,y_0)$ on $\Omega$, the problem $y'=f(x,y)$ admits at last one solution.

My question is: please can you give me an example to show how we can apply this theorem to prouve existence of solution of Cauchy problem $y'=f(x,y), y(x_0)=y_0$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  The problem admits **at most** one solution. Osgood's lemma is used to prove not the *existence* but the *uniqueness* of a solution to an initial value problem (as regards the former, see [Peano existence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_existence_theorem)).

Comment: I don't understand. So what's name of this theorem? Isn't Theorem of Osgood? The lemma who's in my fist message isn't Osgood? What's the Osgood theorem? Plase

Comment: Where did I write that the lemma in your question is not Osgood's lemma?

Comment: Sorry. So the Osgoos lemma say that the Cauchy problem admits at most one solution. Why you say that we use it to prouve unicity of Cauchy problem? And can you give me an example please to show how we use Osgood?

Comment: If the problem has at most one solution (please correct that in the question), then there can be no two solutions to the same initial value problem. Thus uniqueness if a solution exists at all.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. So please can tou give me an example to show how we use this lemma to prouve existence and unicity?

Comment: As LutzL and myself wrote, you can use Osgood's criterion to prove **uniqueness** only. If you are looking for an example, see, e.g., [A question about Osgood condition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122340/a-question-about-osgood-condition).

Comment: So, il we prouve existence then Osgood give us the unicity? And for the example in the topic A question about Osgood condition, how we prouve the existance of the problem? Please

Comment: As I wrote in my first comment, by the Peano existence theorem.

Comment: To apply Peano we have ton consider the problem on $C=\{(x,y): x_0 \leq x \leq x_0+a, |y| < +\infty\}$. We can consider this? How we can choose $a$?

Comment: Please look to [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask): "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page."